# forkjoin not wait for all observables complete when no value emit from each observable

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I have several observables request. 
Each observable request is recursive call and when there is no more data, it will call EMPTY.

for example:

```
request1 = recursive observable call
request2 = recursive observable call
request3 = recursive observable call
```

Then i use forJoin

```
forJoin(request, request2, request3).subscribe();
```

The forkJoin will callback with complete when anyone of them finish. It actually not wait for all observables complete.
I check the rxjs document, it mention

> When all observables complete, emit the last emitted value from each.

As I don't care these observables return value, so it would not emit value to the forkJoin observer. Then i found that in this case if only one complete, forkJoin observer is notified with complete.

Is this the observable limitation that i do need to emit value to able to wait for all observables complete?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's actually very confusing what behavior you need. `forkJoin` won't complete unless all source Observable emit at least one value. If one source just completes and doesn't emit anything `forkJoin` will never complete.

Comment: In my testing, forkJoin actually complete when one emit complete. Finally i work around with to emit one value before complete.

Comment: You can just return of(true) instead of EMPTY, that will complete the stream with a value.

Answer (score 2):

It is [by design](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/56e7cebd211d93b9958e1ec508052beb8927604a/spec/observables/forkJoin-spec.ts#L166).

Reference [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2188#issuecomment-266521238):

> `forkJoin` short circuits if one of the streams completes without emitting a value.

Since [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/empty) just emits 'complete' and nothing else, `forkJoin` will complete right there.

Actually, the other non-empty observables inside `forkJoin` will still be subscribed, but since `forkJoin` may complete before them (depends on when did the `EMPTY` appear in `forkJoin`), you may not be able to handle them inside the `forkJoin`'s `complete` function.